# Navbar toggler icon flips to left side when active. Covers logo that is aligned to left

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using a collapsible navbar in Bootstrap 4. I have the menu items right-aligned with a left-aligned logo. When the screen size is decreased and the navbar toggler is active, the menu items are hidden (on the right) but the toggler icon appears on the left. It overlaps with the logo. I want the toggler to stay on the right.

I've tried giving it absolute position, using navbar-toggler-right, etc. I also tried putting the button inside a div and using justify-content-between.

Here's a link to a Codepen with the code I've written.

https://codepen.io/amandathedev/pen/bOrZZq

The images are all hosted locally because this is just a project for practice, so they don't appear in the Codepen preview. I hope it's still easy to tell what's happening with the logo.

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Modern Calligraphy</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="logo.ico" />

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item" id="header">
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar bg-transparent navbar-expand-sm">
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon mr-auto"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
          </button>
          <img src="logo5.png" alt="Logo" class="navbar-brand mr-auto" />
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item cool-link">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item cool-link">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Order</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item cool-link">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Learn</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item cool-link">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="menu">Menu</div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="main">
        <div class="box">
          <img
            src="personalized.jpg"
            alt="Hand lettered calligraphy quote on paper with fruit"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <img
            src="handLettering.jpg"
            alt="Hand lettered quote in open book on map"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <img
            src="digital.jpg"
            alt="Digital calligraphy drawn on iPad held by woman with stylus"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <img
            src="tutorials.jpg"
            alt="Hand lettered quote on notebook with markers"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="footer">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#"> <i class="far fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
        </ul>
        <span>Copyright 2018, Modern Calligraphy Inc.</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-image: url("concrete-texture.png");
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  grid-template-columns: 10em auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 5.5fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header"
    "menu main main main"
    "footer footer footer footer";
}

/* .grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
} */

#header {
  grid-area: header;
}

/* Navbar */
.nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-toggler {
    width: 1em;
    float: right;
    border: none;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
    position: fixed;
}

.cool-link {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cool-link::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  transition: width 0.4s;
}

.cool-link:hover::after {
  width: 95%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {

}

#menu {
  grid-area: menu;
}

#main {
  grid-area: main;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.box {
  background-color: burlywood;
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  color: #292929;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #dadada;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

#footer ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#footer li {
  padding: 0 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

#footer a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#footer span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at your HTML. You place the button above the logo in your HTML. You don't need to change the CSS you have in your Codepen to shift the toggler to the right, but to align it better, you will need a bit more styling.

Take the logo image that you have written like below and place it above the button:

```
<!-- Navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar bg-transparent navbar-expand-sm">

          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon mr-auto"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
          </button>

          <img src="logo5.png" alt="Logo" class="navbar-brand mr-auto" />
```

Switch to this:

```
<!-- Navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar bg-transparent navbar-expand-sm">

          <img src="logo5.png" alt="Logo" class="navbar-brand mr-auto" />

          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon mr-auto"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
          </button>
```

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe it was that simple. I tried for an hour! Thank you so much!

Comment: It happens. I teach javascript development on the side and see more little mistakes like this than complex errors with most of my student's projects. I've stared at a block of code for days trying to solve problems that were actually just minor syntax errors. Especially when I was just starting out.

Comment: Yeah, any time I've really been stuck it's been for something infuriatingly small!

Answer (score 1):

I swapped the HTML for the nav button and the logo image around and comment out the following CSS

```
.navbar-toggler {
    width: 1em;
    float: right;
    border: none;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
    position: fixed;
}
```

https://codepen.io/scheinercc/pen/MZvRaq

```css
body {
  background-image: url("concrete-texture.png");
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  grid-template-columns: 10em auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 5.5fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header"
    "menu main main main"
    "footer footer footer footer";
}

/* .grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
} */

#header {
  grid-area: header;
}

/* Navbar */
.nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*.navbar-toggler {
    width: 1em;
    float: right;
    border: none;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
    position: fixed;
}*/

.cool-link {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cool-link::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  transition: width 0.4s;
}

.cool-link:hover::after {
  width: 95%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  
}

#menu {
  grid-area: menu;
}

#main {
  grid-area: main;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.box {
  background-color: burlywood;
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  color: #292929;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #dadada;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

#footer ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#footer li {
  padding: 0 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

#footer a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#footer span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Modern Calligraphy</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="logo.ico" />

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item" id="header">
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar bg-transparent navbar-expand-sm">
          <img src="logo5.png" alt="Logo" class="navbar-brand mr-auto" />
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon mr-auto"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item cool-link">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item cool-link">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Order</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item cool-link">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Learn</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item cool-link">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="menu">Menu</div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="main">
        <div class="box">
          <img
            src="personalized.jpg"
            alt="Hand lettered calligraphy quote on paper with fruit"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <img
            src="handLettering.jpg"
            alt="Hand lettered quote in open book on map"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <img
            src="digital.jpg"
            alt="Digital calligraphy drawn on iPad held by woman with stylus"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <img
            src="tutorials.jpg"
            alt="Hand lettered quote on notebook with markers"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="footer">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#"> <i class="far fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
        </ul>
        <span>Copyright 2018, Modern Calligraphy Inc.</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```